# laravel fetching data how to aligned in single line

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7

I'm new in laravel and html im able to get data from table using foreach. but i get data not aliened as I required help me.

**my required alignment**
[image]
**now I'm getting alignment**
[image]

```
@foreach ($Subject_Of_Examination as $user)
                                       
   <td style=" text-align: center; position: absolute; " > <font size="3"><p>{{$user->subject}},</p></font></td>
                                       
@endforeach
```

Comment: why `position: absolute`?

Comment: Hi, try using something like GridJs, where you can define datatables and then create a resource controller to fetch the data. It's a bit of a read and some trial and error. But in the future you will be better equiped to handle datatables. 

I will always be challenge, also use a good pure css framework and follow their docs.

Css frameworks:
Tailwind, Boostrap 6

Comment: @Jack im fetching this data on image

Comment: then why using td? Just put `{{$user->subject}},` or, even better, 
 without foreach, just `collect($Subject_Of_Examination->pluck('subject'))->join(', ')`. I'm on my mobile, this can fail, but you can get the way